# Windows batch file to hide multiple extensions in folder and subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file in a directory that hides a particular extension from the directory and its subfolders. I would like to know how to add more than one extension.

```
attrib /s +h *.srt
```

I would like to hide not only *.srt files, but also *.log, *.xml and *.jpg in the same batch file.

Comment: Obviously, you can use one line for each extension.

Comment: You can also do it using one or more of the [tag:for-loop] types, `/F`, `/R`, `/D /R`, or a standard one. Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the information presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the extensions into a `for` loop.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (.srt .log .jpg .xml) do attrib /s +h *%%i
```

See `for /?` from `cmd` to learn more about the command.